# How to balance reward multipliers and XP purchase cost?

Tags: game-design, balance, progression

I'm working on a school simulation game with an in-game currency called gems.

In the game, there are 2 groups of people: teachers and learners.

Teachers create classes, and learners attend them. Prior to attending each class, learners can deposit a certain amount of gems which highlight their confidence in completing the challenges in the class. Each teacher has a reward pool which grows and shrinks over time based on learner interest.

In the class, learners encounter several challenges and need to complete them before the time runs out. If the time runs out, they lose 20% of their initial deposit. The 20% gets sent to that teacher's reward pool, thus increasing the stake from others. Learners also have the option to take part in a course without a deposit, but they earn no gems from it.

Teachers earn gems daily at 00:00 UTC. They can use the gems to improve their classroom, buy new equipment and so on. A teacher's gem reward rate is determined by three things:

- The number of gems staked in their classes in the last 24 hours
- The number of gems staked across the school in the last 24 hours
- A fixed reward multiplier determined by a teacher's level in the game

```
N gems staked in their classes over the last 24 hours / Total gems staked across the gane in the last 24 hours) x fixed reward rate
```

All teachers start on Level 1, and through completing milestones on the game, they can earn XP towards the next level. The highest level they can reach is 50. I just copied the below from Duolingo.

- Level 1: 0 → 59 (60 point span)
- Level 2: 60 → 119 (60 point span)
- Level 3: 120 → 199 (80 point span)
- Level 4: 200 → 299 (100 point span)
- Level 5: 300 → 449 (150 point span)
- Level 6: 450 → 749 (300 point span)
- Level 7: 750 → 1,124 (375 point span)
- Level 8: 1,125 → 1,649 (525 point span)
- Level 9: 1,650 → 2,249 (600 point span)
- Level 10: 2,250 → 2,999 (750 point span)
- Level 11: 3,000 → 3,899 (900 point span)
- Level 12: 3,900 → 4,899 (1,000 point span)
- Level 13: 4,900 → 5,999 (1,100 point span)
- Level 14: 6,000 → 7,499 (1,500 point span)
- Level 15: 7,500 → 8,999 (1,500 point span)
- Level 16: 9,000 → 10,499 (1,500 point span)
- Level 17: 10,500 → 11,999 (1,500 point span)
- Level 18: 12,000 → 13,499 (1,500 point span)
- Level 19: 13,500 → 14,999 (1,500 point span)
- Level 20: 15,000 → 16,999 (2,000 point span)
- Level 21: 17,000 → 18,999 (2,000 point span)
- Level 22: 19,000 → 22,499 (3,500 point span)
- Level 23: 22,500 → 25,999 (3,500 point span)
- Level 24: 26,000 → 29,999 (4,000 point span)
- Level 25: 30,000 → 34,999 (5,000 point span)
- Level 26: 35,000 → 39,999 (5,000 point span)
- Level 27: 40,000 → 45,999 (6,000 point span)
- Level 28: 46,000 → 52,999 (7,000 point span)
- Level 29: 53,000 → 59,999 (7,000 point span)
- Level 30: 60,000 → 67,999 (8,000 point span)
- Level 31: 68,000 → 76,999 (9,000 point span)
- Level 32: 77,000 → 86,999 (10,000 point span)
- Level 33: 87,000 → 96,999 (10,000 point span)
- Level 34: 97,000 → 107,999 (11,000 point span)
- Level 35: 108,000 → 120,999 (13,000 point span)
- Level 36: 121,000 → 133,999 (13,000 point span)
- Level 37: 134,000 → 147,999 (14,000 point span)
- Level 38: 148,000 → 163,999 (16,000 point span)
- Level 39: 164,000 → 179,999 (16,000 point span)
- Level 40: 180,000 → 196,999 (17,000 point span)
- Level 41: 197,000 → 215,999 (19,000 point span)
- Level 42: 216,000 → 235,999 (20,000 point span)
- Level 43: 236,000 → 256,999 (21,000 point span)
- Level 44: 257,000 → 278,999 (22,000 point span)
- Level 45: 279,000 → 301,999 (23,000 point span)
- Level 46: 302,000 → 326,999 (25,000 point span)
- Level 47: 327,000 → 352,999 (26,000 point span)
- Level 48: 353,000 → 380,999 (28,000 point span)
- Level 49: 381,000 → 409,999 (29,000 point span)
- Level 50: 410,000

I'm having difficulty calculating the following and need some help:

- How should the fixed reward multiplier tie in with the teacher's level in the game? As this determines how many gems they earn, I want it to be as fair as possible.
- Teachers also have the option of exchanging gems for XP, however, this is discouraged, as the preference is for teachers to create classes and attract learners. However, I want the option to still exist but at a very high cost. What would be the best way of calculating this?

Comment: Ask yourself, how fast do you want them to access it. How much efford in days should an upgrade be worth. Test the game, play it yourself in a small group. Simulate a few weeks of play time. There is no `fair` value, everyone will perceive it differently. Numbers are just numbers, without having played your game, numbers are just numbers.

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine the "fairness" of a reward multiplier? What specific fair outcomes do you aim to achieve, or what unfair outcomes do you seek to avoid? To calculate a fair price for XP, we'd need more information: the rates at which XP can be earned without buying it directly, the amount of utility players gain from investing gems in other ways, and the expected gem earning rate for different classes of teacher, from new/inexperienced to "endgame", etc.

Comment: As an aside, please tell me you're not using blockchain for this. These mechanics can be implemented much more efficiently (and with greater ease for you to tune and balance them if you get the initial mechanisms wrong) with more conventional technologies.